# How to create a hyperparameter tuning step in SageMaker pipeline?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters, mlops

I am trying to use the latest SageMaker Python SDK (v2.23.0) to implement a SageMaker pipeline that includes a hyperparameter tuning job. However I didn't see anything in module sagemaker.workflow.steps or sagemaker.workflow.step_collections that I can use. There is a TrainingStep class but it's not for HPO.

Is this not supported at this time?

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker Pipelines now supports a TuningStep to integrate Hyperparameter Tuning jobs in a Pipeline.

This example [notebook](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/tuning-step/sagemaker-pipelines-tuning-step.ipynb) shows how you can do this.

Source: AWS Employee